# escape `|' in \verb

Tags: verbatim

In LaTeX, if I use `\verb`, how can I escape `|`? For example, I want to display `ab|bc`: `\verb|ab[]bc|`. What should replace `[]`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
\verb=ab|cd=
```

you can choose any symbol as a delimiter for the verb argument, except the `*`, it is reserved for `\verb*=a b=` (`\textvisiblespace`)

[image]

Comment: I chose "!". Bad choice... There may be more characters which cause errors.

Comment: Sure, it depends to the setting of active characters, like the one from Babel and German language, foe example.