# What characters can delimit the argument of \verb?

Tags: verbatim, delimiters

I have seen `\verb`'s argument delimited by many characters. I started out with `" "`, then I saw it done with `# #` and verified it worked, and I just saw it done with `| |` [right here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203578/columnbreak-doesnt-work) in egreg's answer. So I was wondering: what other characters can be used? Is there any difference in using one delimiter or another? In fact, seeing [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/escape-in-verb) makes me wonder: is there any symbol I *can't* use with `\verb`?

Comment: `*` is the only one (apart from a space, of course). But sticking to `|` or `!` or `"` is better.

Comment: Is there any reason to choose a specific delimiter except for "aesthetic" reasons (which are reasons of taste alone) and needing a character inside the `\verb` as in the case of the linked question?

Comment: @egreg `=` is also quite common

Comment: And characters with `\catcode` 11 (letter) can't be used, can they? What `\catcode`s allow characters to delimit `\verb`'s argument?

Comment: \catcode isn't so relevant as they are made safe (changed) anyway so you can even use `%` if you want

Comment: Up till it gets to 11, because `\verba` will surely not be interpreted as `\verb` with `a` as delimiter, right? And neither will `\verb\ ` be taken for a `\ `-delimited `\verb`, right? But then if I (I certainly won't, but in the absurd hypothesis I did) changed `%` to catcode 11 or escape, it couldn't be used as a `\verb` delimiter either, could it? So `\catcode` _is_ relevant, unless I wrote some bogus up there :).

Comment: @MickG Getting a letter delimiter is a bit tricky but doable: we need to tokenize `\verb` without tokenizing what follows. For example `\makeatletter\@firstofone{\verb}a#%a`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`*` makes `\verb*` so can't be used for the non-star form without hacking internals, but apart from that any character may be used, the reason is that you need to choose a character that is *not* in the string that is being set verbatim.

Note that latex doesn't make *all* symbols safe in verbatim (or for the verb delimiter)
If you try to use an ascii null (byte 0) as the delimiter you get

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.6 \verb^^@
```

Comment: Which means if I change `"` to the `\catcode` of `^^@` (ASCII null) it will give the same error if I use `"` for the `\verb` delimiter, right?

Comment: @MickG yes the error is nothing to do with verb: latex sets \catcode0=15 so 0 is an illegal character pretty much anywhere and its verbatim code doesn't (but could) change that