# How can I put a vertical line | within the \verb command

Tags: verbatim

How can I put a vertical line `|` within the `\verb` command to get something like this [image]

Comment: Like this: `\verb+DEFAULT (PRIVATE | FIRSTNAME | SHARED | NONE)+` ?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203585/what-characters-can-delimit-the-argument-of-verb