# A verbatim-like environment, but inline

Tags: verbatim

I would like to find a solution to use a verbatim-like environment, but inline. Indeed, I would like to ask not to compile Latex functions but just for a specific place in a text.

I tried this :

```
    Equation vectorielle en utilisant la commande
 \begin{verbatim} \boldsymbol \end{verbatim}:
```

But the problem is that there is a line jump.

Comment: What exactly do you want in the output?

Comment: (are you looking for \texttt or \verb?

Comment: `Equation vectorielle en utilisant la commande  \verb|\boldsymbol|`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\verb` --- for example

```
Equation vectorielle en utilisant la commande  \verb|\boldsymbol|
```

You can use [almost any symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203588/38080) after `\verb` to delimit you "verbatim" text (but not `*`!); choose one that does not appear in the internal material:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
a verb with bars: \verb|\foo| or with plus: \verb+a vertical bar|+
\end{document}
```

[image]